# should rt2800usb module not be included on raspberry version?

Tags: package-management, usb, kernel, raspberrypi

I am on the latest LTS version, `uname -r` returns `5.15.0-1017-raspi` running on a Raspberry Pi Zero 4.

Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Module rt2800usb seems to not be included, even if it's supposed to be included in all distributions from version 3. modinfo or modprobe for rt2800usb says the module isn't found, and I can't find any reference for it on any file in my system.

trying `find /lib/modules -type f -name 'rt2800usb.ko'` doesn't return anything either.

Is it supposed to be included? Or am I missing something? I already ran `update`, `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above, apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) should work, but will not survive an upgrade.

Instead, install
the linux-modules-extra-raspi meta-package, which will ensure that upgrades
work correctly, and that supporting packages are also installed.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporal stop-gap, you can run

```
apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Note that this is a temporal solution, as any upgrade to the kernel will break your driver. However, the required driver seems to be strangely absent from the raspberry ubuntu distributions, even if it's part of the core kernel.
I've raised a bug, but nothing else that can be done, other than installing that package.